# Does honey contain animal proteins?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, is-it-vegan, protein, honey

From a nutritional standpoint, is honey vegan? Or does it contain animal proteins?

<sup>related: "[Is honey considered vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/219/811)"</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honey contains only trace amounts ([~1mg per gram of honey](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3492327/#pone-0049164-t001)) of proteins, and they come from the bee, as [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3492327/#p-43) found:

> All proteins identified in the four honey types belonged to two groups of *Apis mellifera* proteome: the MRJP [Major Royal Jelly proteins] family and the enzymes involved in carbohydrate metabolism.

(Whether insect proteins are considered animal proteins would be another question.)

1 tbsp of raw honey:

[image]

Compare this to an equal amount of whole cow's milk, which has a significantly higher amount of (animal) proteins:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, honey is not considered vegan regardless of the origin of any protein, simply because it is the result of beekeeping, and bees are animals.