# Can "vegan" mean "lacking animal proteins"?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, protein, terminology

Can "vegan" mean "lacking animal proteins" (as opposed to "harming animals" etc.), in order to emphasize the nutritional differences and health effects of animal vs. plant protein consumption?

<sup>inspired by this question: "[Does honey contain animal proteins?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/2613/811)"</sup>

Comment: `Does anyone define ...?` and `Who defines ...?` are both poll type questions ... it is unclear why you require a list of people that fit into that category ... please try wording your question differently, because as it stands, your question is off topic here

Answer (score 1):

The [Vegan Society](https://www.vegansociety.com/go-vegan/definition-veganism) defines veganism as

> ...a philosophy and way of living which seeks to exclude—as far as is possible and practicable—all forms of exploitation of, and cruelty to, animals for food, clothing or any other purpose; and by extension, promotes the development and use of animal-free alternatives for the benefit of animals, humans and the environment. In dietary terms it denotes the practice of dispensing with all products derived wholly or partly from animals.

So by that definition, excluding animal proteins is insufficient.